# ilike operator performing differently in openerp 7

Tags: odoo

i know operator ilike already with regard to sql. It will perform this way when placing in where class

```
 'PSS01' ilike 'pss01' -> will return true
 'PSS01' ilike '%ss01' -> will return true
 'PSS01' ilike 'ss01' -> will return false
```

But in openerp 7, it performs this way

```
 'PSS01' ilike 'pss01' -> returns true
 'PSS01' ilike 'ss01' -> returns true **(it should return false)**
```

My code is below

```
 repeted_ids = prod_serial_obj.search(cr, uid, ['&',('name', 'ilike', line.prod_ser_no),('product_id', '=', product_id)])
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

OpenERP automatically wraps the right handed value of `ilike` operator inside percents. So when you write the domain

```
[('name', 'ilike', 'ss01')]
```

OpenERP convert it to

```
name ilike '%ss01%'
```

To avoid having these wildcard characters added, you have to use the `=ilike` operator.

```
[('name', '=ilike', 'ss01')]
```

will be converted to

```
name ilike 'ss01'
```